# Flutter/Dart: Reuse widget multiple times and return setState value

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using a `DropdownButton` widget many times on one page in my app. In order to prevent rewriting of code, I'd like to use the widget once and pass values to it. The issue I'm having is that I need to setState the "value", which cannot occur when passing an argument to the mentioned method. How does one go about reusing a widget structure, and have it `setState` for multiple different values? My example below:

```
String trial;

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return SafeArea(
  child: Scaffold(
    body: Column(
      children: [
            //TRIAL
            dropDownLists(
              hint: "Trial",
              items: ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
              value: trial, //<---This value does not update when option chosen
            ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

//Method

```
Widget dropDownLists({String hint, List<String> items, String value}) {
    print(value); //<--- null, but giving a value throws errors because a value 
                  //doesn't match an item on the list
    return DropdownButton<String>(
      hint: Text(hint),
      value: value,
      onChanged: (selectedValue) {
        print(selectedValue);
        print(value);
        setState(() {
          value = selectedValue;
        });
      },
      items: items.map((String selection) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: selection,
          child: Text(selection),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
```

Issue: DropdownList works up until a value needs to be selected. Once a value is selected, it is not shown as being chosen

Theory: I currently am not returning the value properly, but don't know how to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```dart
String trial;

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return SafeArea(
    child: Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          dropDownLists(
            hint: "Trial",
            items: ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
            value: trial,
            onChange: (value) => setState(() => trial = value),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}

Widget dropDownLists({
  String hint,
  List<String> items,
  String value,
  Function(String) onChange,
}) {
  print(value);

  return DropdownButton<String>(
    hint: Text(hint),
    value: value,
    onChanged: onChange,
    items: items.map((String selection) {
      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
        value: selection,
        child: Text(selection),
      );
    }).toList(),
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought it might have something to do with passing a function, but I just wasn't getting it correct. Thanks a bunch